# get all rows from database if one row matches filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a web service that sends information about products to the user, but only if the information has been updated. So, for example, I have a table with translations and I want to get all translations for this product, but only if one `updated_at` row of one of these translations is higher than a specific timestamp. Would this be possible in one single query?

This is my translations table in this example:

```
+---------------+
| Translations  |
+---------------+
| product_id    |
| slug          |
| value         |
| language_code |
| created_at    |
| updated_at    |
+---------------+

SELECT * FROM Translations WHERE product_id IN (1, 2, ...);
```

Currently I am always loading the translations for all products and filtering them out using php code. However, this puts a big load on my server at that moment and I would like to reduce that.
I always want to send all translations for a product when one is updated so the enduser knows it can remove all existing translations and add these instead.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a sub-query that returns product_id for those products having a  updated_at value later than the specific timestamp. `Join` with that result to get those products' all rows.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select distinct product_id
      from tablename
      where updated_at > :that_timestamp) t2
  on t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I couldn't get it to work with the join though, but your query gave me the idea to use a `WHERE IN` with the same subquery.

Comment: `IN` is pretty much the same. Strange that my query didn't work though.